# Trying to install coreutils via MacPorts: "Error: Port coreutils not found"

Tags: linux, macos, unix, macports, coreutils

I'm trying to use MacPorts to install coreutils.

I check that MacPorts was installed correctly,

```
$ port version
Version: 2.3.4
```

and try to install coreutils,

```
$ sudo port install coreutils
Error: Port coreutils not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you install any other packages?

Is there anything unusual about your internet connection, like a VPN or a proxy, or any restrictions that might keep rsync from working?

Have you tried using a [different mirror](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors)?

Do `sudo port -v sync` and `sudo port -v selfupdate` spit out any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I've tried all of those things =/