# MacPorts can't find ports

Tags: macos, rsync, macports

### Problem

MacPorts can't find any ports. Example:

```
sudo port install wget
Error: Port wget not found
```

---

### Similar questions

In this post, [Trying to install coreutils via MacPorts: “Error: Port coreutils not found”](https://superuser.com/questions/1058255/trying-to-install-coreutils-via-macports-error-port-coreutils-not-found), @Different55 suggested the diagnostics of `sync` and `selfupdate`, as did @mm49307 in this post: [Macports port not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790412/macports-port-not-found)

**sync**

```
sudo port -v sync
Password:
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from 
rsync://rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/ports.tar
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: No route to host (65)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-
51/rsync/clientserver.c(106) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzvl --delete-after --
include=/ports.tar --include=/ports.tar.rmd160 --exclude=* 
rsync://rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/  /opt/local/var
/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarba
lls
Exit code: 10
Error: Synchronization of the local ports tree failed doing rsync
port sync failed: Synchronization of 1 source failed
```

**selfupdate**

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
Password:
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: No route to host (65)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-
51/rsync/clientserver.c(106) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzvl --delete-after 
rsync://rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/base.tar 
 /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/macports/
release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
```

---

### Environment

MacPorts version

```
port -v
MacPorts 2.4.1
```

OS Version

```
system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType

Software:

System Software Overview:

  System Version: macOS 10.12.5 (16F73)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 16.6.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Computer Name: *****************
  User Name: ******* (*******)
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Time since boot: 7 days 23:42
```

Proxy variables

```
echo $https_proxy 
http://proxyout.***.***:8080
echo $http_proxy 
http://proxyout.***.***:8080
```

Proxy settings

[image: settings]

---

### Question

How do I get MacPorts to work?